# MonoDroid - Draw Ellipse in runtime

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I am newbie in MonoDroid. How can I draw ellipse in runtime using C# in Android Application?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to draw an ellipse on a custom control/surface? Or do you want to add an ellipse to some part of your layout somewhere?

Comment: I mean is there smth like Shape class from .Net in Android Sdk? Or i must to use algorithm for drawing ellipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw an ellipse, or other geometric shapes, you can use the canvas object.  Here's a very basic bit of code that will draw an ellipse (oval).  I basically just created a view and overrode the OnDraw method to draw the ellipse.  You define a RectF object which defines the rectangular boundary of the ellipse.  A good reference is the Android SDK:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

```
    [Activity(Label = "MonoAndroidApplication1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class Activity1 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        var targetView = new OvalView(this);
        SetContentView(targetView);
    }
}

public class OvalView : View
{
    public OvalView(Context context) : base(context) { }

    protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        RectF rect = new RectF(0,0, 300, 300);
        canvas.DrawOval(rect, new Paint() { Color = Color.CornflowerBlue });
    }
}
```